ggplot2 raincloud plot using gghalves + ggdist not correctly plotting data?
i could well be missing something obvious here but i'm starting to think this might be a bug (?) i've been at it so long. im plotting a raincloud plot using ggplot2, gghalves, ggdist. i'm looking at how average unique competitors at a nesting hollow per day for some birds might be influenced by the years a breeding pair has bred (categorised into one-time vs repeat breeders in my column breeder status) inferring that repeat breeders have some kind of advantage from somewhere. I've got my raw data with some half-eyes showing their distribution and then a summary statistics line over it.
i've noticed that every time i re-run this plot some of the point values change (substantially?) but they are absolutely not matching the dataset. values display something random just aren't present in my dataset. i've tried almost everything under the sun at this point. jittering settings were what i thought might be the case - but doesn't seem to be. simplifying the plot, removing the coord_flip() function, changing the range_scale value, updating r and all packages - etc.
here's a snippet of my data which appears to still be doing it for me:
data <- tibble::tribble(
  ~nobroods, ~avg_uniq_comp, ~hollow_breeder_status,
        4,    0.1500000,             "repeat",
        3,    0.2666667,             "repeat",
        1,    0.6000000,           "one-time",
        1,    0.6000000,           "one-time",
        3,    0.2666667,             "repeat",
        1,    0.2000000,           "one-time",
        2,    0.3000000,             "repeat",
        2,    0.4000000,             "repeat",
        2,    0.4000000,             "repeat",
        1,    0.4000000,           "one-time"
)

here's the code using ggplot, gghalves, ggdist and the oli_hawkins pilot theme package (library(pilot) #remotes::install_github("olihawkins/pilot")
uniquecompplot <- ggplot(data, 
                         aes(x = hollow_breeder_status, 
                             y = avg_uniq_comp,
                             colour = hollow_breeder_status, 
                             fill = hollow_breeder_status)) +
    gghalves::geom_half_point(aes(shape = as.factor(nobroods), 
                                colour = "Summary statistics"),
                           side = "l", #choose right or left side 
                            range_scale = 0.05, # spread of points
                            alpha = .6,
                            size = 2.2,
                            position = position_identity()) +
  ggdist::stat_halfeye(
    adjust = .4,           # smoothness of distribution
    width = .87,           # height of distribution
    colour = NA) +
  labs(title = "Breeder status' relationship to unique competitors per day",
       subtitle = "Summary statistics: general linear model results over raw data",
       x = "Breeder status",
       y = "Average unique competitors per day") +
  coord_flip() +
  pilot::scale_color_pilot() +
  pilot::scale_fill_pilot() +
  pilot::theme_pilot(grid = "",
                     axes = "b") + 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        axis.text.y = element_text(face = "italic"),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 16),  # Adjust title size
        plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 12)) + # Adjust subtitle size 
  scale_shape_manual(name = "Number of broods",  # Add legend for Nobroods
                     values = c("1" = 16, "2" = 17, "3" = 15, "4" = 8)) + # Specify shapes manually
  guides(colour = FALSE, fill = FALSE) +
  scale_color_manual(name = NULL,  # Add legend for boxplot colours
                     values = c("Summary statistics" = "black")) +  # Specify the custom color  
  lims(y = range(seconddataun$avg_uniq_comp))  # Set the y-axis limits to match the extent of your data

uniquecompplot

i've been in the depths of absolutely everything and cannot find a solution.

Stripping back the code to isolate the problem, plot p1 captures the visual change resulting from the default transformation position_jitter().
Using position_identity() instead, p2 gives identical results on each run.
You could also set a seed = 1 inside position_jitter() if jittering is required.
library(tidyverse)
library(gghalves)

data <- tribble(
  ~nobroods, ~avg_comp, ~status,
  4, 0.1500000, "repeat",
  3, 0.2666667, "repeat",
  1, 0.6000000, "one-time",
  1, 0.6000000, "one-time",
  3, 0.2666667, "repeat",
  1, 0.2000000, "one-time",
  2, 0.3000000, "repeat",
  2, 0.4000000, "repeat",
  2, 0.4000000, "repeat",
  1, 0.4000000, "one-time"
)

# 2 runs with position_jitter()
p1 <- ggplot(data, aes(status, avg_comp, colour = status, fill = status)) +
  geom_half_point(aes(shape = as.factor(nobroods)))

p1


p1



# 2 runs with position_identity()
p2 <- ggplot(data, aes(status, avg_comp, colour = status, fill = status)) +
  geom_half_point(aes(shape = as.factor(nobroods)),
                  transformation = position_identity())

p2


p2


Created on 2024-04-06 with reprex v2.1.0

Thank you! I wanted to jitter but this helped me figure it out. Appreciate it :)
For anyone elses reference, this is what worked in the end. I also changed the transparency (alpha = 0.6) of my halfeye plots to allow for the points to be semi visible in there. using the command transformation instead of position and also using jitterdodge instead of jitter.
transformation = position_jitterdodge(jitter.width = 0.8))

You can also set a seed for reproducibility in both jitter and jitterdodge.
